# Rails 3 - Building a nested resource within another nested resource (articles -> comments -> votes)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, build, resources, nested, associations

In my app there is an association problem, which I'm unable to fix.
My app is quite simple: There's an Article model; each article has_many comments, and each of those comments has_many votes, in my case 'upvotes'.
To explain the way I designed it, I did a comments scaffold, edited the comment models and routes to a nested resource, everything works fine. Now, I basically did the same process again for 'upvotes' and again edited model and routes to make this a nested resource within the comment nested resource. But this fails at the following point:

```
NoMethodError in Articles#show
Showing .../app/views/upvotes/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:
undefined method `upvotes' for nil:NilClass
```

My _form.html.erb file looks like this:

```
<%= form_for([@comment, @comment.upvotes.build]) do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field "comment_id", :value => :comment_id %>
<%= image_submit_tag "buttons/upvote.png" %>
<% end %>
```

Why is 'upvotes' undefined in this case, whereas here:

```
<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |form| %>
rest of code
```

everything works totally fine? I copied the same mechanism but with @comment.upvotes it doesn't work.

My upvotes_controller:

```
class UpvotesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @upvote = Upvote.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @upvote }
    end    
  end

  def create
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
    @upvote = @comment.upvotes.build(params[:upvote])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @upvote.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@article, :notice => 'Voted successfully.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @article, :status => :created, :location => @article }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to(@article, :notice => 
        'Vote failed.')}
            format.xml  { render :xml => @upvote.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

end
```

I'm sorry for this much code.., my articles_controller: (extract)

```
def show
    @upvote = Upvote.new(params[:vote])
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @comments = @article.comments.paginate(page: params[:page])


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @article }
    end
  end
```

And my 3 models:

```
  class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :body, :title

    has_many :comments
  end

  class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :content

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :article
    has_many :upvotes
  end

  class Upvote < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :article_id, :comment_id, :user_id

    belongs_to :comment, counter_cache: true
  end
```

Upvote migration file:

```
  class CreateUpvotes < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      create_table :upvotes do |t|
        t.integer :comment_id
        t.integer :user_id

        t.timestamps
      end
    end
  end
```

My routes:

```
  resources :articles do
      resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy] do
        resources :upvotes, only: [:new, :create]
      end
    end
```

Sorry for that much code. If anyone might answer this, they would be so incredibly awesome!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is 'upvotes' undefined in this case, whereas here:

This is because you're calling upvotes on a nil object, the comment doesn't exist yet.

Best thing to do would be looking into nested attributes:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/2_3_release_notes.html#nested-attributes

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/2_3_release_notes.html#nested-object-forms

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the links!
However, one question:
Why is the comment a nil object? I thought I defined it with `@comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])` in my upvote_controller?

Comment: I would suspect you have many comments on the article page, the comment variable should be local e.g  @article.comments.each do |comment| and then use the comment variable to build your upvote forms.

Comment: I think that's the right hint, but I'm unable to implement this. The way the comment list is defined in my articles show action is `@comments = @article.comments.paginate(page: params[:page])`, nothing more. And in the article show view the comments are rendered via `render @comments`. So, how can I give each comment an id, a recognition, that my upvotes and articles controller can work with when the upvote form is submitted (actually just clicked on)? Of course each comment has an id and is nested within an article, but how can that id be accessed?

Answer (score 0):

Your error message, says that you try call `upvotes` on `nil`. Specifically it is a part of code `@comment.upvotes.build` in your `/app/views/upvotes/_form.html.erb` view.

You have to fix `show` action in you `ArticlesController`, by adding `@comment` (with contents) variable.

```
  def show
    @upvote = Upvote.new(params[:vote])
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @comments = @article.comments.paginate(page: params[:page])


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @article }
    end
  end
```

Also strange things are happening in `UpvotesController`, in `create` action.

```
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
@comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
@upvote = @comment.upvotes.build(params[:upvote])
```

Firstly you had fetched one `@article` using `params[:id]`, then you had fetched all comments of that `@article` (throught association), where comments id is the same as `@article` id. Please review your code, it is inconsistent and will not work correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I agree that I had to define my @comment in the show action of my articles_controller. However, I don't have any ideas left how. I tried `@comment = @article.comments.find(params[:comment_id])` due to my hidden_field `<%= f.hidden_field "comment_id", :value => :comment_id %>` but now I get the error "Couldn't find Comment without an ID", so my main problem seems to be that the id of the comment simply doesn't get defined correctly. I did fix the code in the upvote controller.

Comment: You are welcome! Please explain, what do you want to achieve in your `ArticlesController#show` ? You want yo show `1 article` with `1 comment`? Or article with comments list?

Comment: It should be 1 article with a comments list. I feel like the problem is that since comments are nested within the articles, the comment_id isn't submitted correctly; in my understanding such a submit would need to include both the article.id and comment.id of the comment that's voted on. I feel like my upvote form needs to be fixed `<%= form_for([@comment, @comment.upvotes.build]) do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field "comment_id", :value => :comment_id %>
<%= image_submit_tag "buttons/upvote.png" %>
<% end %>

`

Answer (score 0):

Everything fixed and works fine now. Took a different approach and simply used Upvote.new instead of nesting it into the comments and building associations, edited my routes as well. Implemented Matthew Ford's idea

> I would suspect you have many comments on the article page, the comment variable should be local e.g @article.comments.each do |comment| and then use the comment variable to build your upvote forms.

Thanks everybody for your help!